# PHP Fetch all rows from MySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch all rows for `parentId` for my form. However my below code isn't able to fetches just 1 record, into my array:

```
public function getChildByParent($parentId)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT childId, nick, relation FROM childId WHERE parentId = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $parentId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($childId, $nick, $relation);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $user = array();
    $user['childId'] = $childId;
    $user['nick'] = $nick;
    $user['relation'] = $relation;
    return $user;
}
```

I understand that I need to tweek around `$stmt->fetch()` and `$user = array()` to fetch_all. Can you help me work around this code?

Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$stmt->get_result()` to setup `$result->fetch_all()` to get all records in one call.

**Try:**

```
public function getChildByParent($parentId)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT childId, nick, relation FROM childId WHERE parentId = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $parentId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $stmt->close();
    return $user;
}
```